# Can you use "pvcreate" with a USB flash drive as a device on Ubuntu?

Tags: partition, lvm, usb-drive

Is it possible to run `pvcreate` command choosing a USB flash drive as a device?

When I executed `pvcreate` command on Ubuntu:

```
sudo pvcreate /dev/sdc # */sdc* is a USB device
```

I got the error:

```
Device /dev/sdc not found (or ignored by filtering).
```

Here are the device properties

```
    Disk /dev/sdc: 14.7 GiB, 15728640000 bytes, 30720000 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xcad4ebea
Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdc4  *      256 30719999 30719744 14.7G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

Comment: Do you have filtering configured in /etc/lvm/lvm.conf?

Comment: Also, the output from `pvcreate -vvv /dev/sdc` may have more details.

Comment: I have not configured anything in /etc/lvm/lvm.conf , what do I have to do??

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://serverfault.com/questions/720868/pvcreate-device-dev-sdxx-not-found-or-ignored-by-filtering

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to create a physical volume on bootable media i.e.USB. As seen device /dev/sdc4 is an active device and its bootable partition. So by default, you cannot use pvcreate command on it.

Suppose if you use the command pvcreate /dev/sdc4 then this message is shown 
**Can't open /dev/sdc4 exclusively.  Mounted filesystem?**
Because its already mounted.

So to create any physical volume on your hard disk space first create a new partition under it and then use pvcreate command.

Suppose if you created a new partition with the name /dev/sdc5 and try to use pvcreate command i.e. pvcreate /dev/sdc5 and the same error is flashes ( Device /dev/sdc5 not found (or ignored by filtering)). Then use the -vvv option i.e.(pvcreate -vvv   /dev/sdbc5).

or Add new Hard disk on your machine and then try to use pvcreate command. This will definitely work. Suppose your new hard disk name is /dev/sdb of size 2gb then use pvcreate /dev/sdb and it will create a physical volume.

Answer (score 0):

If `/dev/sdc` is not listed in `/proc/partitions` (check with `cat /proc/partitions`) you can do:

```
sudo partprobe /dev/sdc
sudo pvcreate /dev/sdc
```

and it should work.

Comment: I checked "/sdc"  is in the list: `major minor  #blocks  name

  
   8       32   15360000 sdc
   8       36   15359872 sdc4
`

Comment: @Yaron anyway I tried `sudo partprobe /dev/sdc` and the result is the same

Comment: What does the output of dmesg return when you run the pvcreate command?

Comment: I can't find it in the dmesg output